# Vuejs Code doesn't work in component yet works in app

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-component

So I had a pretty awesome vuejs app that was working flawlessly however it fails when I put it into a vue component. I keep getting the following error. **[Vue warn]: Error compiling template** Heres the code for my component that I am including (**components.php**) :

```
    <script>Vue.component('profileinfo', {
  template: `<div id="profileInfo">
        <div class="sectionHeader">Profile</div>
        <div class="dataPoint">First:&nbsp;{{firstNameBraintree}}</div>
        <div class="dataPoint">Last:&nbsp;{{lastNameBraintree}}</div>
        <div class="dataPoint">Company:&nbsp;{{companyBraintree}}</div>
        <div class="dataPoint">Email:&nbsp;{{emailBraintree}}</div>
        <div class="dataPoint">Phone:&nbsp;{{phoneBraintree}}</div>
        <div class="buttonDiv">
            <input class="button" type="button" value="Update" v-on:click="showUpdateProfileForm()">
        </div>
      </div>
<!--Show Update Profile Form-->
<div class="updateProfileForm" v-show="showupdateprofileinfoform==true">

      <h2>Update Account Information</h2>
            <h2>Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></h2>
      <!--PASSWORD-->
      <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show="passwordLengthMet==true && passwordHasCap==true && passwordHasNum==true || password.length=='' && passwordHasCap==false && passwordHasNum==false">Password * <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
          <p v-show="passwordLengthMet==false && password.length!='' || passwordLengthMet==true && passwordHasCap==false || passwordLengthMet==true && passwordHasNum==false">Password * <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Password must be at least 8 characters, Have a capital letter and contain a number</span></i></p>
       <input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="********" v-on:focus="showpasswordrequirements">
         <ul v-show="dispassr==true">
          <li v-show="passwordLengthMet==false || password==''">Must contain at least 8 characters</li>
             <li v-show="passwordHasCap==false">Must contain capital letter</li>
             <li v-show="passwordHasNum==false">Must contain number</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END PASSWORD-->

      <!--PASSWORDS MATCH-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show="passwordsMatch==true">Confirm Password* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Passwords Match</p>
         <p v-show="passwordsMatch==false">Confirm Password* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please make sure passwords match</span></i></p>
     <input type="password" v-model="confirmPassword" placeholder="********" v-on:focus="showconfirmpasswordrequirements">
        <ul v-show="disconfr==true">
        <li class="blue" v-show="passwordsMatch==false || confirmPassword==''">Please be sure your passwords match</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END PASSWORDS MATCH-->

      <!--FIRSTNAME-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show="validFirstname==true">First name* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
      <p v-show="validFirstname==false && sub==1">First Name* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please enter your firstname</span></i></p>
        <p v-show='validFirstname==false && sub!="1"'>First Name* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Please enter a firstname</span></i></p>
        <input v-model="firstName" placeholder="Firstname" v-on:focus="showfirstnamerequirements">
        <ul v-show='disfnamer==true'>
        <li v-show="validFirstname==false">Please enter a firstname</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END FISTNAME-->

      <!--LASTNAME-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show="validLastname==true">Last Name* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
      <p v-show="validLastname==false && sub==1">Last Name* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please enter your lastname</span></i></p>
        <p v-show='validLastname==false && sub!="1"'>Last Name* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Please enter a lastname</span></i></p>
        <input v-model="lastName" placeholder="Last name" v-on:focus="showlastnamerequirements">
        <ul v-show='dislnamer==true'>
        <li v-show="validLastname==false">Please enter a lastname</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END LASTNAME-->

      <!--EMAIL-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
        <p v-show="validEmail==true">Email* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
        <p v-show="validEmail==false && email!=='' || email=='' && sub==1">Email* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please enter a valid email</span></i></p>
        <p v-show="email=='' && sub==0">Email* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Please enter a valid email</span></i></p>
      <input v-model="email" placeholder="jchang@example.com" v-on:focus="showemailrequirements">
        <ul v-show='disemailr==true'>
        <li v-show="validEmail==false">Please enter a valid email</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <!--END EMAIL-->

        <!--PHONE -->
        <div class="inputDiv">
        <p v-show="phoneLength==true && phoneHasNum==true && phoneNumber!=''">Phone* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
        <p v-show="phoneLength==false && phoneNumber!='' || phoneHasNum==false && phoneNumber!='' || phoneNumber=='' && sub==1">Phone* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Phone Number must have at least 10 numbers and have no letters, parenthis or dashes</span></i></p>
        <p v-show="phoneNumber=='' && sub==0">Phone* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Phone Number must have at least 10 numbers and have no letters it cannot contain parenthis or dashes</span></i></p>
        <input v-model="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number 1234567890" v-on:focus="showphonenumberrequirements" id="phoneNumber">
        <ul v-show="disphoner==true">
        <li v-show="phoneLength==false">Phone number must be 10 numbers long</li>
        <li v-show="phoneHasNum==false || phoneNumber==''"> Phone number must contain only numbers</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <!--END PHONE-->

        <!--COMPANY NAME-->
        <div class="inputDiv">
            <p v-show="validCompanyName==true">Company Name* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
            <p v-show="validCompanyName==false && companyName!='' || companyName==false && companyName=='' && sub==1">Company Name* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please enter your company name</span></i></p>
            <p v-show="companyName=='' && sub==0">Company Name*  <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Please enter your company name</span></i></p>
            <input v-model="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" v-on:focus="showcompanynamerequirements">
            <ul v-show="discompr==true">
            <li v-show="validCompanyName==false">Please enter your company name</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
        <!--END COMPANY NAME-->

       <div class="inputDiv">
                <div class="sliderWrapper">
                    <div><strong>Subscribe to Email List</strong></div>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="subscribe" value="1">
                <span class="slider"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="inputButton">
      <input v-on:click="updateAccount()" type="button" class="saveProfileButton" value="Update">
    </div>
    <div class="inputButton">
          <input v-on:click="hideUpdateProfileForm()" type="button" class="cancelProfileButton" value="Cancel">
    </div>
  </div>
<!--End Update Profile Form-->`,
  data() {
    return {
    showSpinner: false,
    showupdateprofileinfoform: false,
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    sub: '',
    subscribe:'',
    dispassr: '',
    disconfr: '',
    disfnamer: '',
    dislnamer: '',
    disemailr: '',
    disphoner: '',
    discompr: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    companyName: '',
     customerId: '<?php echo $customer->id; ?>',
    companyBraintree:'<?php echo $customer->company; ?>',
    firstNameBraintree:'<?php echo $customer->firstName; ?>',
    lastNameBraintree:'<?php echo $customer->lastName; ?>',
    phoneBraintree:'<?php echo $customer->phone; ?>',
    emailBraintree:'<?php echo $customer->email; ?>',
    phone:'',
    updated: ''
    }
  },
    computed: {
    passwordsMatch: function() {
        this.confirmPassword=this.confirmPassword.replace(/\s/g, '');
      if(this.password == this.confirmPassword) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    passwordLengthMet: function() {
        this.password=this.password.replace(/\s/g, '');
      if(this.password.trim().length >0 && this.password.trim().length >= 8) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    passwordHasCap: function(){
      if(/[A-Z]/.test(this.password)){return true;} else{return false;}         
    },
    passwordHasNum: function(){
      if(/[\d]/.test(this.password)){return true;} else{return false;}  
    },
    validEmail: function() {
        this.email=this.email.replace(/\s/g, '');
      var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
      if (!reg.test(this.email)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
      validLastname: function() {
          this.lastName=this.lastName.replace(/\s/g, '');
          if(this.lastName.trim().length<1){return false;} else {return true;}
      },
      validFirstname: function() {
          this.firstName=this.firstName.replace(/\s/g, '');
       if(this.firstName.trim().length<1){return false;} else{return true;}   
      },
      validCompanyName: function(){
          if(this.companyName.trim().length<1){return false;} else{return true;}
      },
      phoneHasNum: function(){
          if(isNaN(this.phoneNumber)){return false;} else {return true;}
      },
      phoneLength: function(){
          this.phoneNumber=this.phoneNumber.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
          if(this.phoneNumber.trim().length==10){return true;} else{return false;}
      }
  },
    created: function() {
      this.subscribe=1;
      this.firstName='<?php if(isset($_SESSION['firstname'])){echo $_SESSION['firstname'];}?>';
      this.lastName='<?php if(isset($_SESSION['lastname'])){echo $_SESSION['lastname'];}?>';
      this.email='<?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){echo $_SESSION['email'];}?>';
      this.companyName='<?php if(isset($_SESSION['companyname'])){echo $_SESSION['companyname'];}?>';
      this.phoneNumber='<?php if(isset($_SESSION['phonenumber'])){echo $_SESSION['phonenumber'];}?>';
  },
  methods: {
  showUpdateProfileForm: function(){
      this.showupdateprofileinfoform=true;
  },
  hideUpdateProfileForm: function(){
  this.showupdateprofileinfoform=false;
},
    updateAccount: function() {
        this.sub=1;
      if(this.validFirstname && this.validLastname && this.validEmail && this.passwordsMatch && this.validCompanyName && this.phoneHasNum && this.firstName!='' && this.lastName!='' && this.email!='' && this.phoneNumber!='' && this.companyName!='' && this.passwordLengthMet && this.passwordHasNum && this.passwordHasCap && this.password!='' && this.confirmPassword!='' || this.validFirstname && this.validLastname && this.validEmail && this.passwordsMatch && this.validCompanyName && this.phoneHasNum && this.firstName!='' && this.lastName!='' && this.email!='' && this.phoneNumber!='' && this.companyName!='' && this.password=='' && this.confirmPassword=='') {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify({
          firstName: this.firstName,
          lastName: this.lastName,
          password: this.password,
          email: this.email,
          phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
          companyName: this.companyName,
          subscribe: this.subscribe
        });

        $.ajax({
          url: 'updateAccountInfoBackend.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'post',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: jsonString,
            error: function(data){
              alert('error');
//                window.location.href='successfullycreated.php';
            },
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
              alert('success');
              if(data.updated==1){location.reload();}
              if(data.updated==0){location.reload();}
          }.bind(this)
        });
    }
    },
      showpasswordrequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=true;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      },
      showconfirmpasswordrequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=true;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      },
      showfirstnamerequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=true;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      },
      showlastnamerequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=true;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      },
      showemailrequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=true;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      }, 
      showphonenumberrequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.disphoner=true;
           this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.discompr=false;
    },
      showcompanynamerequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.disphoner=false;
           this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.discompr=true;
      }
  }
});
```

**Heres the code for the vue app itself:**

```
<?php session_start(); ob_start(); unset($_SESSION['accountupdated']); unset($_SESSION['inserteddisplay']); unset($_SESSION['updateddisplay']); unset($_SESSION['creditcardupdated']);
if(isset($_SESSION['didnotdelete']) && $_SESSION['didnotdelete']==1){header('location:unabletodelete.php');}
if(isset($_SESSION['accessdenied']) && $_SESSION['accessdenied']==1){header('location:logout.php');}
if(isset($_SESSION['accountupdated']) && $_SESSION['accountupdated']==0){header('Location:updateaccountinfoerror.php');}
if(isset($_SESSION['kill']) && $_SESSION['kill']==1){header('Location:updateaccountinfoerror.php');}
if(isset($_SESSION['creditcardnotupdated']) && $_SESSION['creditcardnotupdated']==1){header('Location:errorupdatingcreditcard.php');}
if(isset($_SESSION['didnotinsertdisplay']) && $_SESSION['didnotinsertdisplay']==1){header('Location:errorinsertingdisplay.php');}
if(isset($_SESSION['displaynotauthorized']) and $_SESSION['displaynotauthorized']=1){header('Location:notautorizedtoupdatedisplay.php');}
if(isset($_SESSION['didnotupdatedisplay']) && $_SESSION['didnotupdatedisplay']==1){header('Location:didnotupdatedisplay.php');}
$validyear=$_SESSION['validyear'];
$currentmonthyear=$_SESSION['currentmonthyear'];
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
  $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
//if(isset($_GET['id']) and $_GET['id']!=$_SESSION['braintreeid']){header('Location:logout.php');}
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){header('Location:logout.php');}
  require_once 'lib/Braintree.php';
  require_once('head.php');
  require_once('header.php');

  $gateway = new Braintree_Gateway([
    'environment' => 'sandbox',
    'merchantId' => 'key',
    'publicKey' => 'key',
    'privateKey' => 'key'
  ]);

  $customer = $gateway->customer()->find($id);
  $plans = $gateway->plan()->all();

  $plansArray = array();

  foreach ($plans as $plan) {
    array_push($plansArray, $plan);
  }

  $subscriptions = array();

  foreach ($customer->creditCards as $card) {
    foreach ($card->subscriptions as $subscription) {
      array_push($subscriptions, $subscription);
    }
  }
?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Get Customers</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="vue.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
     <?php require_once('components.php');?>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="app">
      <div class="profile-containter">
     <profileinfo></profileinfo>
          </div>
    </div>
    <!--End Update Display Form -->
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {

          },
          methods: {

          }
        });

      </script>
    <?php include('foot.php');?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Again the strange thing about all this is that it works perfectly if I just leave it in a vue app yet it does not work all of the sudden when I place it in a Vuejs component. I find this very, very strange as it is essentially the same code. If any of you genius coders have any suggestions I would appreciate it. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Looks like your template don't has single root element, I wrapped it with another `div` and it works.

Comment: That worked but why? I have it wrapped in a div with a class of profile-container why doesn't that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Max Sinev mentionned, your template does not have a *single* root element, which is not possible (see the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element)).

In order to fix that, you only need to wrap all your html code in a single `div` like so:

```
<div>
    <div id="profileInfo">
    ...
        <div class="inputButton">
          <input v-on:click="hideUpdateProfileForm()" type="button" class="cancelProfileButton" value="Cancel">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```